# Plyr arrange() sorts only 1 variable

Tags: r, plyr

Objective: sort a dataframe by descending order of 2 variables independently using arrange() from the plyr package

```
 dd <- data.frame(b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
                        levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
             x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
             z = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
  arrange(dd, desc(y),desc(z))
```

produces the objective:

```
    b x y z
    1 Low C 9 2
    2  Hi A 9 1
    3  Hi A 8 1
    4 Med D 3 1
```

However when using the same syntax with actual dataframe of interest (**ddin**),
arrange() sorts only 1 variable at a time, leaving the other un-sorted.

Some specifics about **ddin**: large dataframe. The first operation was to subset to keep only 3 variables:

```
ddin_sub <- select(ddin, var1, var2, var3)
ddin_sub <- arrange(ddin_sub, desc(var2), desc(var3))
```

var2, var3: numeric

Any thoughts about where the issue could lay? Thanks.

Comment: You may have to show an example that doesn't work. `d1 <- data.frame(y = c(8, 2, 9, 9), z=c(3, 5, 2, 1));arrange(d1, desc(y), desc(z))` works as expected.  Do you expect it to sort independently?  In that case `d1 %>% mutate_each(funs(sort(.,decreasing=TRUE)))`

Comment: Thanks so much akrun. Yes, to sort the df variables independently. I edited the question to reflect this important requirement. mutate_each() worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to sort columns independently,

```
 library(dplyr)
 mutate_each(d1, funs(sort(., decreasing=TRUE)))
```

#### data

```
 d1 <- data.frame(y = c(8, 2, 9, 9), z=c(3, 5, 2, 1))
```